# Google Cloud Sql private ip with ssl only

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I want to connect from spring boot app in GCP to Cloud Sql with private IP and ssl only for public ip. And i'm not understand "ssl only flag" it only for public connection or public/private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're two different dimensions of security/connectivity.

Public IP means connecting from outside a VPC (https://cloud.google.com/vpc). So it could be an external application (not in Cloud), or maybe an application running in GCP but on a different network (VPC). Private IP means the application and the database share the VPC, or are peered between two VPCs (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering). Basically, with one you're staying within Google's internet sphere, and the other you're probably touching public internet.

SSL is another layer on top of one or the other of those, where you're specifying the keys to allow a user to connect. So checking that "ssl only connections" box means you only want to allow connections to your DB instance which have the private key that matches the key you've registered.

Broadly speaking, our best practice is to use the Cloud SQL Proxy (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) rather than setup your own SSL keys. The proxy also uses SSL keys to ensure secure connectivity as well, but it does it on demand, rather than static keys, which is more secure. The only time you really want to use your own SSL keys, is if you have a specific certificate authority you want to trust and use so you have specific keys you need to use (or you just don't trust Google and want to keep track of your own SSL keys).

Comment: I think the author wants the same thing I want, to connect over a Private IP without SSL, but when connecting via Public IP, SSL is required. Postgres can do this but Google Cloud doesn't expose this option - it only has "SSL on all connections". Fundamentally this is a total pain to get servers and applications to talk to the database instance (certificate permissions, extra packages, extra parameters, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, broadly speaking the pattern for this would be to use the proxy from public IP when needed, as the proxy will handle SSL for you without you having to juggle the certs. The caveats there are: 1) Connection from client to proxy is NOT encrypted, so you'll need to VPN or run the proxy alongside the application, and 2) If you need to use your own certs, obviously that won't work.